# Error while building Spark 1.2.1 on Windows 7 using sbt

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I am trying to build Spark 1.2.1 on Windows with the help of sbt, and I'm running into the following issue:

Edit: The command I ran was sbt/sbt assembly

```
[info] Set current project to spark-parent (in build file:/C:/Programming/spark-1.2.1/)
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Not a valid command: /
[error] /sbt
[error]  ^
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I used the latest sbt Windows installer to install sbt and have Git installed on my machine.

Comment: What command did you run? It looks like sbt is being run in an environment that doesn't know about it. The sbt installer has a bug with it that the env variable has a double slash instead of a single

Comment: You would have got some exception also in between. Can you share the entire run logs?